# BlackBerry - html link to app in App World

Tags: blackberry

I have a BlackBerry app in the app store. I want to link to this app from a web page, so if a user goes to that page on their browser and clicks on the link, that BlackBerry AppWorld app will be launched and the user will be able to easily download the native app.

Its possible to do this on iPhone and Android with links like this

```
<a href="http://itunes.apple.com/us/app/mhmobile/id341550746?mt=8">MyApp</a>

<a href="market://search?q=pname:aero.sita.lab.resmobileweb.android.mh">MyApp</a>
```

Is there a similar way to do this on BlackBerry ?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can use client launch link replace 12345 to your app content id.

```
<a href="http://appworld.blackberry.com/webstore/clientlaunch/12345">My app</a>
```

Answer (score 6):

> All URLs must be in the following format: http://appworld.blackberry.com/webstore/content/XXXX (XXXX = your application ID).
>
> You can find the URL for your application by browsing to your application page on the web store and copying the URL in the browser address bar.

From the FAQ at https://developer.blackberry.com/devzone/blackberryworld/faq.html under

```
11. BlackBerry World Co-marketing
d. Can I embed a hyperlink to the Get it at BlackBerry World logo?
```

Answer (score 1):

I use this link, the same when you share your app to Facebook, Twitter etc from the App World

```
<a href="http://appworld.blackberry.com/webstore/content/[App Id]/">My Blackberry App from App World</a>
```

or

```
<a href="http://appworld.blackberry.com/webstore/clientlaunch/[App Id]">My Blackberry App from App World</a>
```

Answer (score 1):

AFAIK, you can also use:
appworld://content/xxxxxx

Comment: Don't know why this was voted down - it works well for me on a Playbook.  This is helpful - it gives me the option to link to my app in the appworld.  There isn't much documentation on how to do this from an Android app compiled for BB.

Comment: Thanks, ProjectJourneyMan. Maybe the downvoting was because of the "not 100% sure" part. Well, after trying that in an app of mine, now I can say I AM 100% sure it works! ;-)

Answer (score 1):

appworld:// is good because I'm not getting a blank browser window like with http://
(Using Adobe Air on Playbook)