# Application URL at Blackberry storefront

Tags: blackberry, storefront, blackberry-world

Can I know the URL of my product at Blackberry storefront (e.g. from SKU) before it has been submitted?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you [can see here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14803738/119114), the URL to the BlackBerry World store is based on the app's *Content ID*.

So, if your app has a content ID of 1000, your url would be:

```
http://appworld.blackberry.com/webstore/content/1000/
```

I honestly can't remember exactly *when* the Content ID gets assigned, and I don't have a new app I can submit right now.

But, if you've already started adding a definition for your app in the BlackBerry vendor portal, login, then choose **Manage Products**, and then pick the (unreleased) app, to edit the details.  On a page that looks like this, see if you have a Content ID already.  If so, that's what you'll use.

[image]

If not, I'm not sure you're going to be able to generate the URL yet.  I do know that the Content ID is a BlackBerry world unique ID, and it's not simply your own SKU, that you have complete control over.  You can certainly choose to make your SKUs match the BlackBerry Content ID, but you can't force BlackBerry World to take your SKU as the Content ID.  Hope that makes sense.